# How to specify what keys are eligible to expand abbreviations?

Tags: vim

I am trying to use abbreviation for my snippets but do not want them to be expanded accidentally. For instance, if I have "for" abbreviation vim will expand it also when I am writing a comment or a variable name (mostly by hitting space). As a partial solution I can write all names with capital letters but it is a little bit harder to type them all the time. I can also remap space to `<C-V><Space>` but there are other keys which are eligible for expansion, and remapping most of them (e.g. `(,;`...) is the last thing I want to do. Well, there is an option called `iskeyword` which defines what symbols are keywords, but as far as I know it is also used in searching and basic movements. I am comfortable to hit `<Esc>` on expansion, so the best solution for me is limit trigger keys to `<Esc>`.

**The question is**: am I allowed to change non-keyword keys and do not affect searching and movements? Can I disable auto expansion and map `<Esc>` to `<C-]><Esc>` to do manual expansion?

**PS**: I can do all I want with mappings.

```
autocmd FileType php inoremap <buffer><expr><Esc>
    \ is#pattern('for\%#') ? "\<BS>\<BS>\<BS>for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {\<CR>}<Esc>" :
    \ "\<Esc>"
```

However, abbreviations is a better approach. It is easier, it is clean, it highlights special keys.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your original question, but it seems that a better solution might be to use one of the snippet plugins for vim. It would allow you to use the snippets that you want, and won't be triggered just by space.

Comment: Since I have not so much snippets I do not want to install any plugin.